# Every function is a closure?

Tags: c++, javascript, python, terminology, closures

Wikipedia says, that closure - is a function, which has an access to variables, declared outside of the function. There is even an example:

```
function startAt(x)
   function incrementBy(y)
       return x + y
   return incrementBy

variable closure1 = startAt(1)
variable closure2 = startAt(5)
```

But according to most programming languages (including python, javascript, swift, etc.) the next example is correct (written in python):

```
# Script starts
test = "check"

def func(test2):

    def func2():
        return test2 == test

    return func2()

print func("check") // returns TRUE
# Script ends
```

Basically, `func` is not a closure, but it obviously uses variable `test`, declared outside of the function. Does that mean `func` IS a closure?

Even in C++ you can run this:

```
std::string test = "check";

bool func(std::string test2) {
    if (test2 == test)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main() {
    if (func("check"))
        std::cout << "TRUE" << std::endl; // prints TRUE
}
```

Eventually, this makes every function being a closure. Where am I wrong?

Comment: For the C++ example, globals/static variables don't count. The property of interest closures have is that they can refer to temporary, scoped variables.

Comment: @Doval: In other words, instance methods are closures, while static methods or functions are not?

Comment: @Gabe I wouldn't say so, because the user of the method has to have a reference of some sort to the object, whereas with a closure that detail is opaque to the user and it just behaves as a function.

Comment: @Gabe Conceptually, they behave the same, but that's generally not what people mean when they talk about closures either. Closures are about capturing local variables. That's an interesting thing because which local variables get captured depends entirely on what code executes. This is why I said globals/static variables don't count - their location is statically known (i.e. at compile time). Likewise, for a given class it's also statically known which instance fields a method can access.

Comment: @mebob: So a C++ method *isn't* a closure, but a C# method *is* because it can be automatically turned into a delegate, and a delegate with a target object is a closure?

Comment: In the c++ example where you have `(test == test)` did you mean to write `(test == test2)`?

Comment: @Gabe I'm not too familiar with C#, but from what I know, the delegate itself would be the closure, not the method that the delegate invokes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, not every function is a closure.

Wikipedia says:

> ... closure ... is a function or reference to a function **together with a referencing environment** — a table storing a reference to each of the **non-local variables** (also called free variables or upvalues) of that function.

I'd add "non-local and non-global", but the idea is correct.

---

Neither your C++ nor Python examples use closures. In both cases it's just scoping rules allow functions to see their outer scope and global scope.

---

"Closure" happens in the 1st example - `incrementBy` is constructed in and then returned from it's outer function, **capturing argument `x`**. When you assign `variable closure1 = startAt(1)`, you end up having a closure (function) inside `closure1` var which captured argument, which value happened to be `1`, so when you call `closure1(2)` the result is `3` (`1` + `2`).

Think of it as memorizing some information about closure's declaration scope: `incrementBy` retain a memory about insides of `startAt`, specifically a value of it's argument `x`.

In lambda calculus, as I know, those "non-local" variables are called "free", and functions with free variables are called "open terms". Closure is a process of "closing" open terms by "fixing" values of those free variables in aforementioned "environment table". Hence the name.

---

It's worth noting that in Python and JS closure happens implicitly, while in PHP you have to explicitly tell which variables you want to close over (capture): http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php - note `use` keyword in declarations:

```
// equivalent to the 1st example
function startAt($x) { //        vvvvvvvv          vv
    $incrementBy = function ($y) use ($x) { return $x + $y };
    return $incrementBy;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a great answer. Looks like I've lost in the terminology. But, looking back to my python example, can't we say, that `func`, which is being constructed in the global scope, captures variable `test` as `incrementBy` does?

Comment: No, because `test` is global - it is visible from anywhere, unless "shadowed" by some local variable with the same name. Also, and it's more important, it remains it's existence after `func` execution is over. On the other hand, when `startAt` execution is over, `x` would be gone forever if it wouldn't be captured by `incrementBy`. Capturing "saves" `x` from garbage collection.

Comment: Also, don't worry about lambda calculus terminology - it is not required to use closures properly.

Comment: @scriptin `test2` in the Python example isn't a global, though, and is used from the inner function.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo yes, but it is used right away (`return func2()`) in the same scope where it is directly visible, so it isn't captured

Answer (score 4):

Closures are an efficient way to *implement* functions.

I claim that every function is *conceptually* a closure, even in the few languages which don't have them.

<sup>The closed variables are then constants or static data inside the code. But in full-fledged [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) (like in Ocaml, Scheme, Common Lisp, or C++11) the closed variables and the code are in the closure itself.</sup>

For instance, in C (and in C++98) functions are closures, but their *closed* (or *free*) variables are restricted to be `static` or global variables.

Closures also brings the possibility for anonymous functions, e.g. lambdas, which create closures with *new* closed variables (and that is something not possible in standard C). This is the [*abstraction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29) operation of the [λ-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) (which does not exist in C, this is why every callback function -e.g. in GTK- takes some "client data" as an extra parameter).

From an implementation point of view, a function is always some code with some data required by the code. The data are the closed variables. For compiled C code, the data is *wired* in the code as fixed global or static variables (and changing these variables require recompilation), or as literal constants. So the only way of making an abstraction would be to *regenerate* some new code with some new variables in it.

Abstraction does not exist in standard C because there is no way to generate portably new functions. But you could use weird implementation-specific tricks. Imagine that you want to implement the translation generator function. In ocaml, the function to generate the translated-by `delta` function is

```
 let transl delta = fun x -> x + delta
```

and that is generating a new closure for every invocation. So in

```
 let t3 = transl 3 in t3 5
```

a new closure `t3` is generated (but perhaps the optimizer is removing it) and the result is 8 (which is 3+5).

You could do insane tricks in C: on Linux, you would for example *generate at runtime* a new textual file `t3mod.c` containing

```
 int t3(int y) { return y+3; };
```

and you would compile that `t3mod.c` file in a shared object `t3mod.so` and `dlopen` it then `dlsym` it using `"t3"`. This contrived way (using C code generation at runtime, then dynamically loading it) is a way of implementing abstractions in C and it is a way to generate *dynamically* new function pointers. Likewise, you might use [JIT compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries like e.g. [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) (or [`libgccjit`](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/JIT) in future [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 5). Read also about [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) & [eval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval) & [multi-stage programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_programming) (e.g. [Meta OCaml](http://okmij.org/ftp/ML/MetaOCaml.html)...). See also J.Pitrat's blog entries on [meta-combinatorial search](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/10/the-meta-combinatorial-search-much-better-than-the-combinatorial-search/) & [meta-bugs](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/06/the-meta-bug-curse-of-the-bootstrap/).

Comment: "Closures are an efficient way to implement functions." What makes you say that? A closure is generally a function plus an environment pointer, so either your implementation is recursive (if you implement the function in the closure as a closure), or it is not optimally efficient (since the function inside the closure has less overhead than the closure itself).

Comment: "I claim that every function is conceptually a closure" While you can argue that a standalone function is a closure with an empty environment, doing so makes the term "closure" useless.

Comment: The important word is *conceptually*

Comment: Your compiled C code contains an environment, as static or global variables.